# How to migrate a file and all its commit history to a new repo in git?

Tags: git

I have a repo (repoA) and a file in that repo has 20-30 commits; I want to move that file to repoB with all of the commit history; how do I do that?

Comment: AFAIU, the commit history belongs to the repository, not to an individual files. You commit changes to the repo (even if you could *conventionally* decide to commit changes only one individual file at once, which is probably a bad idea)

Comment: Technically possible, if you refactor the commits involving the file, find all the items in the repo that represent those commits, copy them over, then update all the refs and branches manually in the new repo. But why would you want to?

Comment: To put it more simply and directly, the commits *are* the history. There is no such thing as "file history"; there is merely "history, which is the set of all commits". When you run `git log <file>` Git just *avoids printing* some of the history.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to move is the whole branch as it is, just add a new remote pointing to the new repo and push the branch to it. If you have 30 commits with say 50 files and you want to move the history of a "single" file, as if the file was always alone you will have to rewrite the history of the branch so that you get only the history of that file, no more and then you will add the remote and then push to it.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to move changes only from one file and save the history of all repository.

Commits in git aren't about some file. They are about repository.

Maybe you can do something like:

1)get file changes from repoA and copy them in repoB as new commit.

2)after some time push repoB into master for example

3)merge master with repoA. Resolve conflicts if any.